# How to Convert NumPy Array to String and Include Commas

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a NumPy array called 'colors'. Colors has a shape of (N, 3). I'm trying to convert colors into a string and format it so that each item in axis = 0 is seperated by a comma.

```
EX. (1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9), ...
```

I know about the array2string function, but I'm struggling to include commas after converting the array to a string.

Comment: Use `tolist()` to make a list, and format that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert each row to a tuple and then join the string representations of each tuple with a `,`:

```py
a = np.array(((1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9), (10, 11, 12)))
s = ', '.join(str(tuple(r)) for r in a)
print(s)
```

Output:

```
(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9), (10, 11, 12)
```

Comment: thanks that solved my issue. However, there's another small problem I've run into. If I want to append 'x=', 'y=', and 'z=' before each number in each parenthesis, how could I accomplish this?

Comment: @tempaccountforissue that's a little more tricky, but perhaps `'(' + '), ('.join(','.join(f'{names[i]}={n}' for i, n in enumerate(r)) for r in a) + ')'` where `names = ['x', 'y', 'z']`? That will give `(x=1,y=2,z=3), (x=4,y=5,z=6), (x=7,y=8,z=9), (x=10,y=11,z=12)`